# Git repository and TFS repository

Tags: tfs, git-tf

Once upon a time we had a TFS repository. We wanted to move to Git. At the time we took just the latest working version, copied that to a new git repo and started working on that.

However due to decommissioning of TFS we'd like to clone the TFS repo to Git (with git-tf) and rebase our changes on that.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are just talking about the source code (TFS is also a work item tracker, build server among other things)

the **--deep** argument will clone all TFS changesets

```
git tf clone <tfsurl> <teamproject> --deep
```

*update*: bear in mind that this doesn't take into account linked work items, branches, tags.

**beware**: this will take a while for large repositories...

further reading: http://gittf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Clone&referringTitle=Home